# How to run fortran77 program with inputs from file?

Tags: bash, shell, fortran

I run fortran77 program in terminal

```
./program
```

and the program ask for input and output file. What should I write to terminal when I have the names of input and output files in a file - in two columns? I would like to run the program for all rows in the file with names.

Or - how to run a program with input information like parameters?

Or how to write the name of file direct in script? Instead of

```
READ(+,'(A)') OUT
```

Comment: How to write it in code please? Instead of `READ(+,'(A)') IN` and `READ(+,'(A)') OUT`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I made the following program file `prog.f`

```
       program test

       character IN*30,OUT*30,line*80

       PRINT *,'Input file '
       READ(*,'(A)') IN
       OPEN(1,FILE=IN,STATUS='OLD')
       PRINT *,'Output file?'
       READ(*,'(A)') OUT
       OPEN(2,FILE=OUT,STATUS='NEW',BLANK='ZERO')


       read (1,'(a80)') line
       write (2,*) "I read ", line
       end
```

compiled & linked it with

```
gfortran prog.f -o prog
```

I put a text string into an input file

```
echo "Hello World" > in
```

Then I sent the names of the input file `in` and output file `out` to the program

```
$ <<< 'in
out' ./prog
 Input file 
 Output file?
```

and checked the output file

```
$ cat out
 I read Hello World
```

`<<<` works in `bash`. You may prefer piping from `echo` which is more portable,

```
$ rm out
rm: remove normal file 'out'? y

$ echo 'in
out' | ./prog
 Input file 
 Output file?
$ cat out
 I read Hello World
```

Comment: Interesting! And this outta space file arguments...has to be so in fortran? "cpio" is similar, but at least the output you can give seperately. And here: "<inoutfiles ./prog" does not work? With "inoutfiles" containing the lines "in" and "out", "in" containing the data and "out" being a path. My brain hurts.

Comment: @rastafile, It is possible to make fortran read from standard input and write to standard output, at least with some modern versions. In this case redirection is possible as you suggest.

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: I have a slight dejavu -- I think I read something about that special fortran style long time ago. Now it "hit" me. Nice!

Comment: @Arrara, You are welcome :-)

Comment: @rastafile, Yes, fortran is old style and sometimes quite inconvenient. But still there are many big simulation programs (for research and development) than are written in fortran for historical reasons).

Comment: number crunching also I think - benchmarking...

Answer (score 6):

If you are lucky then maybe

```
<infile ./program  >outfile
```

will work. Redirection to give a filedescriptor. Options/arguments???

---

While we earthlings write something like...

```
$ <77in cat >77.out
$ cat 77in >77.out
```

(This copies just `77in` to `77.out`)

...this Fortran77 program/command wanted it's *operands* linewise in one input file/stream:

```
$  <77.io cat
77in
77.out
```

Now if `cat` was something else it would parse first line as input file (containing "hello\nworld" eg.) and the second as file to create.

And that is just the newer, easy way it seems...

---

Instead of a long argument list like `cp -a dir1 dir2 dest` it is `<in_list cpa77`.

But then you need an additional file...just like modern `cpio` does:

`<filelist cpio -o >files.cpio`. Of course `cpio` just needs STDIN linewise:

`find . | cpio -o >files.cpio`

(`cpio` has this special call syntax because of its functioning, working with many files. It is **one command and a half**. Same for `tar`, in a different way)

If anything is typical of unix, then it is this flexibility in feeding control and data to commands in the shell. As I commented: good Q after all! (Thx to accepted answer!)

Comment: Should I replace -o1 -o2?

Comment: @Arrara Yes, I just saw you wrote "parameters". Now these things overlap. A call with argument "-V" as option for "print version" for example.

Comment: I am sorry, I ment output and input as parameters. When I write `<infile ./program >outfile` it does not work

Comment: ...because the correct options are missing.

Comment: What are options please?

Comment: a correct argument might be a star for "all files"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99844/discussion-between-arrara-and-rastafile).

Comment: i see now I was somehow close but that fortran program has that really special SYNTAX: Operands on lines of an input stream. Unlike any cmd today. Good Q after all!